# I want to use output result_Python

Tags: python, parameters, output, store, weibull

I want to use or store output result.

This is my code. I am going to make the prediction graph using output of below.

```
from reliability.Fitters import Fit_Weibull_2P
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300]
rt = [1000, 1000, 1000]
wb = Fit_Weibull_2P(failures=data, right_censored=rt)
```

This is result of above code.

```
Results from Fit_Weibull_2P (95% CI):
             Point Estimate  Standard Error    Lower CI     Upper CI
Parameter                                                         
Alpha          633.486333      272.397421  272.723696  1471.470724
Beta             0.881336        0.274852    0.478285     1.624038
```

I want to use or store "Alpha" and "Beta" as variables.

Comment: so you dont know how to access the data, namely `Alpha` and `Beta`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`wb.alpha` and `wb.beta` to access the values of Alpha and Beta respectively.

They are already variables of the **reliability.Fitters.Fit_Weibull_2P** object,

```
type(wb)
output: reliability.Fitters.Fit_Weibull_2P
```

You can further store the variables like any other variable,

```
a = wb.alpha
b = wb.beta
```